# How to hand drill PCBs?

Tags: pcb-fabrication, hobbyist

Drilling 300 holes in fibre board is tedious, difficult to do neatly and prone to snap bits. What simple methods and tools are available to the home user to drill PCBs effectively?

In my case it's only going to be used occasionally and then on a kitchen table. Apparently a Dremel won't be accurate enough.

Comment: Must have a short bit with a 1/8 or 1/4" shaft and a benchtop drill press for ease, speed and reliable drilling..

Comment: Simple answer: Don't make PCBs with 300 drills at home. There are now plenty of places to get real PCBs made for a reasonable price.  Also 300 drills is quite a lot of vias and the odd thru hole connector.  Get a board that size made professionally.

Comment: Doing PCBs at home is quicker and cheaper. There are as a guess 300 drills but that's across multiple PCBs.

Comment: Doing PCB's at home is quick, but it's only cheap if you you assign a value of zero to your time when doing the calculations.

Comment: I have the Dremel drill press and some carbide drill bits from Harbor Freight.  It works as well as I'd want, but its still slow and a pain in the ass.

Comment: Surface mount everything you possible can.  Even DIP IC's if you bend the pins outwards in a gull-wing configuration.

Comment: It's hard to believe I used to do this in my younger years.

Comment: Are there any safety considerations when drilling fiberglass boards? I've heard that cutting them with saws is a massive fine particle hazard...

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I agree, mounting DIP ICs in a gull-wing or J-lead configuration may be a better approach. Related: ["Is there a standard name for surface-mounted 0.1" pitch DIP packages?"](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/82267/is-there-a-standard-name-for-surface-mounted-0-1-pitch-dip-packages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a drill press for this purpose, remember that the smallest drill bit sizes require the highest spindle speeds, a general purpose drill press won't run fast enough to be ideal. It'll work for a few boards if you're patient and have enough drill bits.

This little one from [Proxxon](http://www.proxxon-tools.com/tools/Proxxon_Drill_Presses.html) and some carbide bits would be a step in the right direction with 8500rpm top speed, but below 1mm even faster would be better.
Just to clarify I'm not endorsing this specific model (though it looks OK), but it's an example of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

What Olin said. You can get PCBs for $1/sq inch qty. 3 if you don't mind waiting a couple of weeks.

If you do mind waiting, then you'll have to spend some money. A carbide 0.030" diameter drill bit wants to turn at least 20,000 RPM to cut cleanly and it can't dwell in the hole. That means that you need to drive it straight down and immediately straight up. You **WILL NOT** be successful doing this solely by hand.

So, what can you do? If you really don't have the room for even a benchtop drill press that takes up less footprint than a laptop computer, your options are limited. Dremel sells (or used to) a cheap small drill press holder for their mini tools that's a bit smaller than a regular drill press. However, it does not maintain alignment very well, so expect to break at least one bit per 300 holes. They also had a small 4" scissor table that would move the workpiece up and down against a fixed tool. That worked a lot better, but I think it was around $100. The Proxxon tool mentioned above looks really good

You can try making your own drill guide out of wood: a block of wood sandwiched between two other pieces so it moves in a straight line and that will work, but I'm guessing you don't have the tools or the woodworking skill to build something that precisely. In any case, it will be very slow and tedious.

Seriously, this is one of those cases when you really are better farming the job out.

Comment: If one needs to do same-day prototypes, phenolic board stock is a lot nicer to work with than fiberglass.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to build a [CNC](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-CNC/) for drilling, your best bet is a small drill press and patience. I find that audio-books are an excellent supplement to tedious otherwise mind numbing tasks.

Additionally I've found that 0805 or 0603 surface mount packages for basic passives are simple to hand solder and cut down on fabrication time considerably.

Answer (score 1):

For small boards (not quite 300 holes!), I have used a thumb drill: [this one](http://www.google.com/patents/USD407289). This is a pen-like instrument with a small chuck which can hold drill bits. You rotate it with your fingers. Though it came with drill bits, I bought a separate set which is both in smaller sizes needed for circuit boards and in an indexed container. You don't want to mix up sizes.

Using it would be a little time consuming for 300 holes, but you can use very thin bits without the risk of breaking (if you are careful). It is like knitting or doing a crossword puzzle: you can do this anywhere, for instance while waiting for something or someone, or riding transit. Any "down time" that you would otherwise waste. 300 holes are done sooner than you think.

In any case, that tool is indispensable when you're replacing through-hole components, for re-drilling a hole which is constricted by remaining solder that won't wick out, or for widening a hole by a mil or two that was incorrectly sized.

DIY circuit boards are time-consuming. You get a fast turnaround time compared to mail order boards, but the cost is not really low unless you pretend that your time is worth nothing.

Comment: I would be a bit cautious about doing this "on the go" where you may not be able to control ventilation or may expose others to fibreglass dust.  It's not asbestos, but it would still be wise to minimise inhalation!

Answer (score 1):

With patience, the *Proxxon Micromot 50/E drill/grinder set with power supply* and *drill stand MB 140/S*.

The quality of Proxxon compared to Dremel is apparent in the video [Drill stand review: Dremel 220-01 vs. Proxxon Micromot MB 140/S](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JyTf1tJXXo)

Answer (score 0):

[image]
 $77 if you can find a store  get extra drill bits with thick shank and short bits.
http://www.harborfreight.com/garage-shop/stationary-drill-press/5-speed-drill-press-38119.html
Overall dimensions: 23" H x 17" W x 7" D

Or buy this[image]

Comment: My experience with the Dremel drill press is that there's too much slop for this application. Fiberglass doesn't have much give, so the little bits snap *very* easily. Maybe it'd be okay for phenolic PCBs, but I would get a "real" drill press.

Comment: Yes some have too much bearing slop.