# is there a standard name for surface-mounted 0.1" pitch DIP packages?

Tags: soldering, packages, history

I've seen several boards that have ICs that look very similar to standard through-hole DIP packages (in particular, the packages have pins on 0.1" pitch), but the boards do not have any holes for the pins of those ICs.

[image]

[image]

Surface-mount components with 0.05" pitch are called "SOIC".
What is the standard name (or a popular name) for these components with 0.1" pitch that are intended to be surface-mounted?
(E.g., components such as the
Fairchild DF04S,
Shindengen S1ZB60-7072,
CEL PS2501AL-1-F3-A,
Toshiba TLP172G,
etc.)
I expected the datasheets for these components to mention some standard name -- like datasheets for other components mention standard packages such as "TO-92", "DPAK", "TQFP", etc. -- but I don't see one.

Is there a standard name (or a popular name analogous to "dead-bug construction") for the process of attaching standard through-hole DIP components to a board without holes?
(The process involves folding their leads one way or the other, gull-wing or J-lead).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a standard name for surface-mounted 0.1" pitch DIP packages?

SMDIP might be the generic term you're looking for - I've seen it used for opto couplers.: -

[image]

As for a standard name for the process of bending thru-hole leads to surface solder leads I can't help except to say maybe it's called "bend 'em with pliers"!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [JEP95 from JEDEC](http://www.jedec.org/category/technology-focus-area/registered-outlines-jep95), which has data/diagrams on over 3000 chip packages. There are so many variants nowadays that it's hard to keep up with the naming (see below).

Regarding some older ICs like in the image, before SOIC, etc I believe [flatpack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatpack_%28electronics%29) was a common surface mount package with such pin spacing. The lower image is an SDIP package as far as I know (it's also used for ["skinny" DIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package#Variants) too, somewhat confusingly)

As to bending the DIP leads, I am not aware of any name for it, it's only used by hobbyists and even then I'd say not so much nowadays. Dead bug or Manhattan prototyping is still very common though, especially for RF stuff.

To give some idea of how many there are, here is a list of the current surface mount packages just from Fairchild, though obviously they are not all unique to Fairchild (from [here](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/package/)):

```
Surface Mount    
ALS
BGA
CSP
Custom
D2PAK/TO263
DO214
DPAK/TO252
Embedded_Die
FLMP
LQFP
LSOP
MDIP
MFP
MICROMODULE
MICROPAK
MICROPAK MLP
MICROPAK2
MLP
MODULE
MOSFET BGA
MSOP
PCB Chip Carrier
PLCC
PQFN
PQFP
PSOF
QSOP
SC70
SOD123
SOD123F
SOD323
SOD323F
SOD523F
SOD80
SOD923F
SOIC
SOP 225
SOP EIAJ
SOT223
SOT23
SOT23F
SOT523F
SOT563F
SOT89
SOT923F
SSOP
SSOP 225
SSOP EIAJ
SSOT
TDI
TSSOP
TSSOPE
Toplooker
UMLP
VSOP
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for the link to Fairchild packages -- that Fairchild page mentions "SDIP" with links to more details about that surface mount package. Is there some reason you didn't include "SDIP" in this list?

Comment: @davidcary - the list is was copied from the Fairchild site and is the packages they currently use for their ICs, so it's not a universal list (it was meant as an example of how many different packages there are to keep track of nowadays). I assume the omission of SDIP on the list just means they don't use the SDIP package.

Comment: My co-worker bought a Fairchild part this week in the sdip package -- a part I mentioned and pictured in my original question -- so apparently they do use the sdip package. The page you linked to does mention that package.

Comment: @davidcary - Ah yes, so it does, my mistake - I was only looking under the "Surface Mount" heading, so I missed it due to it (for some odd reason, must be a classification mistake on their part) being under the "Through Hole" heading...