# DIP package: meaning, dimensions and nomenclature

Tags: packages

I'd like to know exactly what DIP means, since googling it gives me several outright contradictory answers.

I used to assume that DIP and DIL mean these guys only:

[image: Regular DIPs]

That is, through-hole packages with two symmetrical rows, 0.1" (2.54mm) spacing between leads and 0.300"~0.325" (about 8mm) spacing between rows. If I wanted to specify the number of pins, I'd call them DIPn, where n is the total number of pins (obviously, n is always even). I call these guys "regular DIPs".

Then I found out these guys exist, and apparently are also DIPs (I call them "big DIPs"):

[image: Regular DIPs and big DIP]

Then I found out *this* guy exists: ("mutant middle sized DIP"?)

[image: Three DIP sizes side-by-side]

So, lots of questions: are they really all DIPs? If yes, how do I specify which size I am talking about? And what about acronyms like PDIP, CDIP, SDIP and SPDIP? And finally, when referring to pin number, some sources say DIP8 and others 8-DIP. Is there a difference? Also, can I always use "DIL" and "DIP" interchangeably?

Also, Wikipedia tells me SMD DIPs are a thing. What about that?

Comment: DIP = **D**ual **I**n-line **P**ackage. I'm less familiar with DIL but a reasonable assumption is **D**ual **I**n-**L**ine . Both mean any rectangular package with pins on two non-adjacent edges. The term 
"DIP package" is kind of redundant - it's not a dual in-line package package (unless it's a box full of DIP parts)  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DIP and DIL are synonomous.

The width of a standard DIP depends on the pin count. Low pin count DIPs are 0.3 inch row spacing. High pin count DIPs are traditionally 0.6 inch spacing. I think 22 pin and below were traditionally 0.3 inch while 24 pin and above were traditionally 0.6 inch but i'm not 100% sure on the exact cutoff.

A P or C prefix usually reffers to the packaging material. P for plastic C for ceramic.

A S prefix usually reffers to "skinny". This term is used for 0.3 inch wide packages in pin counts that would traditionally be 0.6 inch wide. Typically this is seen with 24 and 28 pin packages.

There was also something called "shrink DIP" which had a smaller pin spacing within the rows but i've never actually seen one.

Surface mount DIPs did exist but were/are rare. Most surface mount chips are SOIC or smaller.

You do occasionally see other variants (in my current project i'm using some optoisolators that come in a 0.4 inch wide DIP). If in doubt check the diagram in the datasheet.

Comment: There tends to be some overlap between 0.3 and 0.6 inch spacing. 24 and 28 pin chips can be frequently found in both widths. Larger than that tend to be all 0.6 from what I've seen.

Comment: Surface mount "DIPs" still exist. I'm aware in particular of the [DI10xS](http://www.panjit.com.tw/pdf/Bridge/DI100S_SERIES%20141114%20REV.02.pdf) rectifiers. I'm not sure what the actual JEDEC package name for that is. "SDIP" seems used by [Fairchild too](https://www.usbid.com/datasheets/usbid/2000/2000-q4/sdip_dim.pdf). Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/82267/is-there-a-standard-name-for-surface-mounted-0-1-pitch-dip-packages

Comment: As Olin Lathrop intended to suggest before he typo'd (or perhaps you edited to insert a few paragraphs), the _last_ paragraph should be 0.4 inches, not 0.4 mm, and these were not often used, except in certain circles: the 100K  ECL family, for instance. Likewise, certain DSP functions such as multipliers and MACs were found in 0.9 inch DIPs.

Answer (score 0):

DIP means dual inline package, was used mainly for thru hole components. I never used DIL.

Like you understood DIP is a family. Letters added to it specify the package material, which is important during the assembly of circuit board and handling of the parts. The number stands for lead count.

According to the size, there is some pitch standards, but you need to look the datasheet of your component to find out the pitch, height and width of your device. The longest leads of your mutants, this is a socket for wire-wrapping. By wrapping a wire around the pin you root your circuit without soldering your components.

SMD (Surface mounted devices) works the same, you got several family of component forms and you need to relate to datasheet for your design.

For package standards, manufacturer generally stands by the JEDEC standards
http://www.jedec.org/

Hope this helps!